# rotate a layout with some buttons

Tags: android, button, rotation, android-sensors

I have a `RelativeLayout` (it is a `Quadrilateral` that has 4 buttons in 4 corners and a button in the center) and I want to rotate it using its `onSensorChanged` method. (I use the magnet and accelerometer sensors to find north).

This code shows how I do it:

```
Log.d("test","befor rotate");
rll.setRotation(20);
Log.d("test","after rotate");
```

This doesn't work, and after the first `Log.d` I see this error:

```
Exception dispatching input event
```

However, this method (`setRotation`) works in another program where I use it to rotate a layout that contains a picture.

What is the problem?

Comment: Post a bit of code. :)

Comment: setRotation is for a camera, try Adding animation to rotate a relativelayout http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html

Answer (score 0):

my problem has solved.
error was here:

```
RelativeLayout rll;
RelativeLayout rll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
```

I rotated layout out of onSensorChanged method. but it had problem in it :)
I think bcz in out of onSensorChanged method, rotate was once run; but in it it was run several times.
I'm right?